# useState Re-renders component only twice when setting same value, but then stops

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

why does `useState` re-renders a component **twice** when setting same value, but, after second render it stops re-rendering, until the given value changes. Example [codepen](https://codepen.io/besokakulia/pen/bZraew).